# How can i read from string[] each second line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), this.ClientRectangle);
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
            int visibleLines = 0;

            for (int i = m_text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                Point pt = new Point((int)((this.ClientSize.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(m_text[i], m_font).Width) / 2),
                    (int)(m_scrollingOffset + this.ClientSize.Height - (m_text.Length - i) * m_font.Size));
                if ((pt.Y + this.Font.Size > 0) && (pt.Y < this.Height))
                {
                    path.AddString(m_text[i], m_font.FontFamily, (int)m_font.Style, m_font.Size,
                        pt, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

                    visibleLines++;
                }
                    Color ccc = Color.Red;
                    if (m_text.Length > 1)
                    test = m_text[i];
                    Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 16);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(test, drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(ccc), pt);
            }
            if ((visibleLines == 0) && (m_scrollingOffset < 0))
            {
                m_scrollingOffset = (int)this.Font.SizeInPoints * m_text.Length;
            }           
            int topSizeWidth = (int)(this.Width * m_topPartSizePercent / 100.0f);
            path.Warp(
                new PointF[4] 
                { 
                    new PointF((this.Width - topSizeWidth) / 2, 0),
                    new PointF(this.Width - (this.Width - topSizeWidth) / 2, 0),
                    new PointF(0, this.Height),
                    new PointF(this.Width, this.Height)
                },
                new RectangleF(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height),
                null,
                WarpMode.Perspective
                );
            e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), path);
            path.Dispose();
        }
```

In this event i added this code:

```
Color ccc = Color.Red;
if (m_text.Length > 1)
test = m_text[i];
Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 16);
e.Graphics.DrawString(test, drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(ccc), pt);
```

But this code will color all the text all the lines in Red. I want one line in Red one line in Green.
Using the DrawString.

There are 10 lines. Let's say i want to read each 2 lines.
Instead now reading every line to read only lines: 2,4,6,8,10
Then if i want how to read for exmaple each 3 lines: 3,6,9

I want to color the first string in Red and color the second string in Green.

```
Line 1: Red
Line 2: Green
Line 3: Red
Line 4: Green
```

And so on all the lines one Red one Green.

Comment: modulo operator if(a % 2 == 0) => second line.

Comment: Smells very much like homework, and has shown no attempt to solve it. Yet highly rated people are doing this user's work for them ...

Comment: Updated my question. I want to color one line in Red one line in Green from the string[] m_text using DrawString. I can color all the text to Red using DrawString but how do i color one line in Red one in Green ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
var brushes = new []{new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new SolidBrush(Color.Green)};

for (int i = 0; i < m_text.Lenght; i++)
{
    ... //other codes
    e.Graphics.DrawString(test, drawFonts1, brushes [i % 2], pt);
}
```

Comment: i think he searches for the modulo operator to know in which line he is (his color thing with color for even / not even rows) (but i don't thinmk anything is wrong with this)

Comment: Better to create a `Brush` array of `Brushes.Red` and `Brushes.Green` instead of simply creating a new `SolidBrush` in the loop or at least dispose the brushes after drawing the string. Otherwise you risk running out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not a hard issue.
Declare a variable with the number of lines you want to "jump" and then use it on your `for` loop.

```
int jump = |whatever you want|
for (int i = 0; i < m_text.Length; i+jump)
{
    test = m_text[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using for loop itself. Try yourself..
1. Initial should be 2
2. Step value 2
3. Color the line in Green Color(since it is in multiples of 2), Color the first line by mtext[i-1] with red color.
```